# silent renew doesn't work on spring-authorization-server and react client

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, single-page-application, spring-security-oauth2

I try to implement authorization flow with spring-authorization-server https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server and react app, i use https://github.com/authts/react-oidc-context library and i managed to achieve so that user can successfully login into application, but when token expires client app tries to sign in silently and starts to spam login requests without any success
[image]
[image]

could it be because of the SameSite attribute?
[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Silent authentication may not work in some browsers, such as safari and brave. [1](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-single-page-app-sdk#get-access-token-with-no-interaction)

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg i've managed to find a solution for this, since authorization server and my front-end app run on different domain you have to add SameSite=None and Secure props to JSSESIONID cookie to make it work in Chrome browser

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it work in Chrome and Firefox you have to add SameSite=None and Secure attributes to JSESSIONID cookie